# WordPress add_query_arg from ajax and make url friendly

Tags: query, htaccess, rewrite-rules

In WordPress I have set a query arg in ajax like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');

function prepare_link() {
    //Do some logic and get the models name
    $url = add_query_arg( array(
            'compare' => aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc,
        ), 'http://example.com/cars/' );
    echo $url;
    wp_die();
}
```

So after this I have got my url like this

`http://example.com/cars/?compare=aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc`

So from jQuery I am doing redirect the page to the response url like this

```
jQuery('a.compare-vechicles').click(function(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: script.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action : 'get_prepare_link',
        },
        success: function(data){
            window.location = data; //Redirect to the prepared link
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to make it as seo friendly url. So the output url should be shown like this

```
http://example.com/cars/compare/aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc
```

So to achieve this I have made like this

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
        'top');
}
```

But its not working at all. So can someone tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Looking at the format - `compare/<slug>` - do you actually have a page having the slug `<slug>` like `aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc`? Because your rewrite rule actually worked for me. So either you didn't flush the permalinks (just visit the Permalink Settings page) or that the page (`aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc`) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This add_query_arg function is add argument after URL you have enter.

You have to get pretty URL so add below code in your functions.php file :

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^cars/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=PAGE_ID&type=$matches[1]&models=$matches[2]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%type%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%models%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);


add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_prepare_link', 'prepare_link');
function prepare_link() {

    $url = "";
    $url .= get_the_permalink( PAGE_ID );
    $url .= "compare/aaa-and-bbb-and-ccc"

    echo $url;
    wp_die();
}
```

**In above code replace "PAGE_ID" with your "car" page id.**

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check? For now Cars is my home page.  I have created a page for compare also.

Comment: No additional changes just replace PAGE_ID with you homepage page id.